# How do I get distinct count values of 2 columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Lets say I have 2 columns, a and b.

Column A contains these values:

```
a
b
c
d
```

Column B contains these values:

```
e
d
c
b
a
```

What can I do to get the absolute distinct values from BOTH columns?

Meaning if i want to have a count on both columns, the result is to be 5. Because a, b, c and d are repeated in column B but not e.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT A
FROM YourTable
UNION
SELECT B
FROM YourTable
```